# Joining columns of different formats

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for an elegant way to reformat data for join purposes.  I have two tables with the same key data, but formatted significantly differently.

I'm using SQL Server.  The data looks like this
Table 1:

```
74-123-58
896-777-92
4567-78
```

Table 2:

```
00007400123
00089600777
00456700078
```

Table 1 has the key split into elements separately by dashes, with the 3rd element (not found in table 2) sometimes missing.

Table 2 always has the first element left zero filled to 6 characters and the 2nd element left zero filled to 5 characters.

I can accomplish this with a very long formula consisting of embedded charindex, left, substring, and replicate functions.  I'd like to write it using something simple, and easier to understand for anyone trying to troubleshoot my code in the future.

Any bright ideas?

Comment: if you want to do it using "something simple", then first you must fix your schema and use proper keys for joins, which also take advantages of indexes. With the current (broken) database, your only way to a join is to put an expression to get a format from the other.

Answer (score 1):

These both look like strings, so use `like`.  You need to do some string munging, but I think this works:

```
select . . .
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.key like cast(left(t2.key, 6) + 0 as varchar(255)) + '-' +
                    cast(right(t2.key, 5) + 0 as varchar(255)) + '%';
```

You should really fix this problem in your data, though.

Note:  The above has a problem because the second key could be 1 and it would match 100.  That can be fixed by ensuring that a hyphen follows.  But, we need to be careful about the two-part keys:

```
select . . .
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.key + '-' like cast(left(t2.key, 6) + 0 as varchar(255)) + '-' +
                          cast(right(t2.key, 4) + 0 as varchar(255)) + '-%';
```

I would strongly advise you to add computed columns to each table that create a standardized format.  You can then create indexes on the computed columns and even get a modicum of performance for such queries.

Comment: Is `+ 0` supposed to cast the expression to integer removing preceding zeros?

Comment: @KamilG. . . . Yes.

Answer (score 0):

These are some other methods.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
  JOIN Table2 t2 on REPLACE(t1.value1,'-','') 
  LIKE cast(left(t2.value2, 6)+ 0 as varchar(255))
       + cast(right(t2.value2, 5) + 0 as varchar(255))+'%'
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
  JOIN Table2 t2 on REPLACE(t1.value1,'-','') 
        LIKE REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(left(t2.value2, 6), '0', ' ')),' ', '0')
             + REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(right(t2.value2, 5), '0', ' ')),' ', '0')+'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which direction you want to go I see two options:

```
on t2.[key] =
    right(
        '000000' +
        left(
            t1.[key],
            charindex('-', t1.[key]) - 1
        ),
        6
    ) + 
    right(
        '00000' +
        substring(t1.[key],
            charindex('-', t1.[key]) + 1,
            charindex('-', t1.[key] + '-', charindex('-', t1.[key]) + 1) -
              charindex('-', t1.[key]) - 1
        ),
        5
    )
```

and:

```
on t1.[key] + '-' like
    cast(cast(substring(t2.[key], 1, 6) as int) as varchar(6)) + '-' + 
    cast(cast(substring(t2.[key], 7, 5) as int) as varchar(5)) + '-' + '%'
```

If you have a version of SQL Server with `format()` you could use that instead of the `right('000000' + X, 6)` method.